# Splunk Dashboard Security

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk, splunk-calculation, splunk-formula

I am from splunk Team, we are noticing that people  who are not the part of splunk team , they are doing changes in existing dashboard , without notifying us .. how can we fix this? can we do something like get notification once any changes done on any dashboard if Yes, then how? please help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent changes in Splunk is through the RBAC model - don't give "others" permissions to write to your KOs

If they have write permissions, they can write

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for the dashboard to make sure only the admin role (or any other role you designate) can write to it.

Splunk does not have a good way to detect/alert on dashboard changes.